# Generic object inside class constructor

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class constructor.
Can someone explain the second parameter? Is Id a function with generic object as first parameter and optional GUID as a second parameter?

```
public myClass(int identifier, Func<T, Guid?> Id)
```

Comment: Well presumably this is declared within a generic class, `myClass<T>`.

Comment: Id is a function that takes generic object and returns a Nullable<Guid>, that is, a Guid or null value

Comment: You should do a bit of research before asking a question. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It says "give me a function that given T (a parameter), can return a `Nullable<Guid>`"

Comment: I always wonder about someone that at least has already a *fair* amount of rep like 700 still doesnt know how SO works and that you should do at first some research on your own. If you didnt undestand that yet, how was it possible to gain 700 rep...

Comment: Guthard, I have more experiences in other areas.
I haven't work with generics and for some quick answer this forum can be really helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Id a function with generic object as first parameter and optional GUID as a second parameter?

Not quite. It is a function with a generic object as a first parameter (the type of `T` is defined elsewhere, probably in the class definition) that *returns* a nullable `GUID`.

Answer (score -3):

.Net is not support generic constructor and there is no meaning to support it because we can achieve this by using class level generic.
Please have a look on below code,

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = new GenericImplementation<int>(1, GetGuid);
        Console.WriteLine( result.Invoke(1));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Guid? GetGuid(int i)
    {
        //Do whateve you want to do
        return new Guid();
    }

}

class GenericImplementation<T>
{
    Func<T, Guid?> _id;
    public GenericImplementation(int identifier, Func<T,Guid?> id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public Guid? Invoke(T value)
    {
        return _id.Invoke(value);
    }

    public bool Equal<U>(U v1, U v2)
    {
        if (v1.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            return v1.ToString() == v2.ToString();
        }

        if (v1.GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            return int.Parse(v1.ToString()) == int.Parse(v2.ToString());
        }

        if (v1.GetType() == typeof(object))
        {
            //Deep level comparision
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Methods can be generic because they can react differently depending on parameter(which is generic) for example equal method, Equal method is work differently depending of provided parameters